# How to process matched regex while looking for next match in java?

Tags: java, regex

Right now in java I am doing this

```
        String finalstring = br.readLine();
        Pattern rx = Pattern.compile("(x?\\d+)");
        Matcher m = rx.matcher(finalstring);

        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(0).toString());
        }
```

to loop through the matches. But this first goes through the entire string creating the groups (i.e. `m`), and then I loop through all the groups. So thats two loops. Is there a way I can do something like

```
        String finalstring = br.readLine();
        Pattern rx = Pattern.compile("(x?\\d+)");
        Matcher m = rx.matcher(finalstring, function(Matcher m) {
            System.out.println(m.group(0).toString());
        });
```

(thats just pseudocode, I mixed in javascript...) But basically I want it so that as soon as it finds a match, I can process it. That way I am only looping once.

Thanks

Comment: Both your examples would run the `println` statement as the pattern is matched, in a single loop. I see no difference in that aspect. What do you want? ---- If you're expecting multi-threaded execution, such that one thread continues searching while another thread processes a result, then forget that. The searching is **very** fast. Look for performance optimization elsewhere.

Comment: Unrelated to question, but your code has a capturing group (parenthesis in pattern), but your not using the result. The captured value is in `group(1)`. `group(0)` is the entire matched value, which by happenstance is the same in this case.

Comment: What makes you think there are two loops here?  Do you think `rx.matcher` loops through the whole string?  (It doesn't; `find` does the walking.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you are confused about what `rx.matcher(finalString)` does. It only initializes the `Matcher` instance, *getting ready* to look at the input.

The input isn't examined until `find()` is called, and even then, it stops scanning when it finds a match.